# What's the most concise way to format a full name in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to generate full names from `title`, `first_name`, `middle_name`, and `last_name`. e.g. Mr Billy Bob Thornton. But the `title` and `middle_name` are optional and I don't want to get any leading or double spaces. I've come up with lots of ways of doing them but none of them seem really elegant. Here are my techniques so far

```
full_name = "#{title} #{first_name} #{middle_name} #{last_name}"
#FAIL. Leading and double spaces result

full_name = "#{title} #{first_name} #{middle_name} #{last_name}".gsub(/^ /,'').gsub(/  /,' ')
#Works but all that regex tacked on the end is very ugly

full_name = "#{title}#{title.nil? || title.empty? ? '' : ' '}#{first_name} #{middle_name}#{middle_name.nil? || middle_name.empty? ? '' : ' '}#{last_name}"
#Works but goes on forever
```

I'll be using rails so can reduce my `.nil? || .empty?` to `.blank?` to make the last one a little more concise but I can't help but think that there's a nicer way.

Comment: Don't forget suffixes: "Junior", "The Third", etc

Comment: You should have a read of this if you haven’t seen it: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: I hadn't seen that @matt, it strikes me as a long list of complaints and problems, and not many (any) solutions. As someone with an apostrophe in his name, I'm very aware of the problems that rigid name restrictions cause.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using Rails so you have access to [`String#squish`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-squish):

> **squish()**
>
> Returns the string, first removing all whitespace on both ends of the string, and then changing remaining consecutive whitespace groups into one space each.

So you could do this:

```
name = "#{title} #{first_name} #{middle_name} #{last_name}".squish
```

Comment: +1 I like the `squish` approach since the approaches that just join with `' '` won't look good if the constituent names have leading or trailing spaces, which is possible if these values come from form elements, say.

Comment: Oh, that is awesome. Been playing with Rails for a couple of years now and had never spotted that one - should read more thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Ruby's [String#squeeze](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-squeeze) and [String#strip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-strip)

```
>> title=""
=> ""
>> first_name="Alice"
=> "Alice"
>> middle_name=""
=> ""
>> last_name=""
=> ""
>> full_name = "#{title} #{first_name} #{middle_name} #{last_name}".squeeze(" ").strip
=> "Alice"
>> last_name="Wu"
=> "Wu"
>> full_name = "#{title} #{first_name} #{middle_name} #{last_name}".squeeze(" ").strip
=> "Alice Wu"
```

Generalizing to a function should be pretty easy.

Comment: Rails wraps these two methods in `String#squish` since it is such a common operation.

Comment: Oh, that's a nice one.  I've been meaning to look into Rails for years now.  Had no idea they extended `String` like that. Someday....... :)

Answer (score 2):

Would you be looking for something like this ?

```
[title, first_name, middle_name, last_name].compact.reject(&:empty?).join(' ')
```

with Rails

```
[title, first_name, middle_name, last_name].select(&:present?).join(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[title, first_name, middle_name, last_name].select({|v| v.present?}).join(' ')
```